# How to change font color of a title in fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, css

I need to change the title color of fullCalendar.
I have used this javascript to center the title.

```
 var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: '',
            center: 'title',
            right: '',
        },
```

Comment: do you have any live demo or live link?

Comment: If you mean the title of the whole calendar use `.fc-center { color: #fff; }` otherwise if you mean the title of an event use `.fc-title { color: #fff; }`

Comment: use proper code indentations please when posting. thank you.

Comment: `color: #0F0;` Try this.

Comment: Only need to change title of calender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use css to change the color of title.

```
.fc-header-title{
       color: #0052ba;
       background: #000;
       font-size: 20px;
}
```